# Do Hunter's Mark and Radiant Sun Bolt interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, monk

Does the extra damage from Hunter's Mark trigger with the Radiant Sun Bolt from the Sun Soul Monk?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## By RAW, No

The bolt in question:

> You gain a ranged **spell attack** that you can use with
> the Attack action.

Hunter's Mark:

> Until the spell ends, you deal an extra 1d6 damage to the target whenever
> you hit it with a **weapon attack**.

But Hex would work:

> Until the spell ends. you deal an extra 1d6 necrotic damage to the target whenever you hit it with **an attack**.

Emphasis mine in all three quotes.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast You mean me trying out AD&D for a second time, this time in the newest edition? Yeah, I joined a mini-campaign a couple months ago, and now it turned into a full-fledged campaign (at which point I even started asking questions in chat here), and, well, thus here I am, engaging in study of the rulebooks of the new system.

Comment: I hope you are enjoying it, and by the way, nice answer. 